# Formula for working out the greatest power that another number is divisible by

Tags: notation, factoring, perfect-powers

Is there a formula to answer the question

> What is the highest value of $n$ where it is true that $b^n$ is a factor of $x$?

where $b$ and $x$ are known positive integers and $n$ is an unknown non-negative integer?

Visually, it's the same as asking

> How many zeros are at the end of $x_b$?
>
> There are $n$ zeros at the end of $x$ represented in base $b$. What is the value of $n$?

So, where $x$ is 45000 and $b$ is 10, $n$ is 3 because 45000 is divisible by $10^3$ but not by $10^4$. This is easy to solve as an iterative computer program but I don't know how it would be solved mathematically.

Is there a formal mathematical way of writing (and solving) this problem?

Comment: To do this for general $x$ requires knowing the factorization of $x$ as a product of powers of distinct primes. That known, $n$ has to be the least power of all primes in the factorization, then $b$ can be computed from $x,\ n.$

Comment: @coffeemath That sounds harder (more computationally expensive) than the original problem.

Comment: @coffeemath I think you misunderstood the question. I'm only trying to find $n$. $x$ and $b$ are already known. I'm not trying to solve $n$ for all $b$, just for a single known $b$.

Comment: CJ... Oh. If x and b are already known you're right the problem is different. How are you counting the computational expense? For example if you just kept trying the powers of $b$ to see if each is a divisor of $x$ and stop when the least power which doesn't work occurs [then report one less power], what expense would that be assigned? Does it cost more to try greater divisors, or how to rate each etc...

Comment: @coffeemath It just seems that there's no better method than trial and error. Try $b^1$. If it's divisible, try $b^2$. Repeat increasing $n$ each time until it fails. You then have the answer. Or divide $x$ by $b$. If there's no remainder, repeat. Count the successful attempts. That is $n$. I'm just wondering if there's a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: CJ So if one does what you describe in your last comment, and it takes $n+1$ steps to know the answer is $n,$ then do you count that as having computational expense proportional to $n$? [versus having the cost be nonlinear in increasing $n$] And I don't know of a cheaper method, without first finding the prime factorizations of both $x$ and $b.$

Comment: Do $b^{2^k}$ until it no longer divides, then do a binary search.